# adding a class using jquery does not have any effect

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show "No Data" right in middle of my div,using the following :

```
  $errorDiv = $('<div>NO  DATA</div>').addClass('NoData');
  $("#pieChart").html($errorDiv.html());
```

here is the class:

```
.NoData{
    margin-top:15%;
    background-color:lightblue;   
    width: 100%;
        }
```

but this only writes the text,without color and position i set in the class

the parent CSS:

```
.card {
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
transition: 0.3s;
width: 40%;
}
```

and HTML:

```
 <div class="card" style="float:left;width:20%">
         <div id="pieChart" style="height:350px"></div>           
      </div>
```

Comment: $('<div>NO  DATA</div>') is supposed to be a selector

Comment: try `$("#pieChart").html($errorDiv);`?

Comment: @SimosFasouliotis not true. Can wrap any html in `$()`. Read the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because `$errorDiv.html()` does not include the outer html of `$errorDiv`

There are sevel ways to do it:

```
$errorDiv = $('<div>NO  DATA</div>').addClass('NoData');
$("#pieChart").html($errorDiv);
```

or

```
$errorDiv = $('<div>NO  DATA</div>').addClass('NoData');
$("#pieChart").html($errorDiv[0].outerHTML);
```

**Working demo**

```js
$errorDiv = $('<div>NO  DATA</div>').addClass('NoData');
$("#pieChart").html($errorDiv);
```

```css
.NoData {
  margin-top: 15%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" style="float:left;width:20%">
  <div id="pieChart" style="height:350px"></div>
</div>
```

**Updated demo**

```js
$errorDiv = $('<div>NO  DATA</div>').addClass('NoData');
$("#pieChart").html($errorDiv).parent().addClass('color');
```

```css
.NoData {
  padding-top: 15%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.color {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" style="float:left;width:20%">
  <div id="pieChart" style="height:350px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks and how can i make the whole background colorful?i mean the background of parent also

Comment: You want the background color on `pieChart` ? @mrslt

Comment: yes because its inside a div,its a Card layout,i want to make the card blue also,when there is no data

Comment: @mrslt Try look at the updated demo, if its not what you want, update your html code and css so we can see what you have.

Comment: @Updated my question

Comment: @mrslt Try check demo 2

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted,you are appreciated

Comment: @mrslt No problem, happy to help